# use the same lock object at two different code block?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Can I use the same lock object at two methods, accessed by two different threads? Goal is to make task1 and task2 thread safe.

```
object lockObject = new object();

// Thread 1
void Method1()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        // task1
    }
}

// Thread 2
void Method2()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        // task2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same lock object (it's technically a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) in the computer science sense, and is implemented with calls to methods in [System.Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) in two different methods.

So, say that you had some static resource `r`, and you wanted two threads to access that resource, but only one thread can use it at a time (this is the classic goal of a lock).  Then you would write code like

```
public class Foo
{
    private static object _LOCK = new object();

    public void Method1()
    {
        lock (_LOCK)
        {
            // Use resource r
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        lock (_LOCK)
        {
            // Use resource r
        }
    }
}
```

You need to lock around every use of `r` in your program, since otherwise two threads can use `r` at the same time.  Furthermore, you must use the same lock, since otherwise again two threads would be able to use `r` at the same time.  So, if you are using `r` in two different methods, you **must** use the same lock from both methods.

EDIT: As @diev points out in the comments, if the resource were per-instance on objects of type `Foo`, we would not make `_LOCK` static, but would make `_LOCK` instance-level data.

Comment: my bad. I wanted to say lock(lockObject)

Comment: You should explicitly call out the fact that the lock object is `static`, and thus the resource it is protecting should be `static` as well; if r were a resource available on the instance level, an instance level lock object would probably work out better.

Comment: Actually it is not an instance of `System.Monitor` cause that's a static class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx

Comment: @dlev, please explain why it would happen.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prevent different threads from performing task1 and task2 at the same time, then you *must* use the same lock object.

If the two tasks do not contend for the same resources, you could use different lock objects.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes.

You can and it works. If you don't use the same object, the blocks could execute at the same time. If you do use the same object, they can't.

Also, you mean `lock(lockObject)`, not `using(lockObject)`.